# Tooltip location in Tourist.js page tour (with Bootstrap collapse)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tourist.js

When I'm opening and closing a bootstrap collapse panel using the `setup` and `teardown` functions of a [Tourist.js](http://easelinc.github.io/tourist/) ([github](https://github.com/easelinc/tourist)) tour step, the following step's tooltip appears where the target was before the panel collapsed.

I can understand that the tooltip's position is calculated and is it is displayed before the collapse animation has completed from the previous step, but I have no idea how to solve it.

I have reproduced the problem in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikecmpbll/amdu8zLa/ (click 'Start tour', then click next and you'll notice if you scroll down that the tooltip is right at the bottom)